# Selecting nth child element based on parent elements attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm running into a bit of a problem using Linq to XML to query this not-so-hot xml document.

An example of the schema is like so.

```
<Data>
    <Row Oper="" Val="THIS">
       <Col Oper="" Val="">
           <Out Val="0"/>
           <Out Val=""/>
           <Out Val="16600"/>
           <Out Val="10000"/>
       </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row Oper="" Val="THAT">
        <Out Val=...">
        ....
    </Row>
</Data>
```

Basically; I need to match the main element based on Row Val and then get nth "Val" based on an arbitrary number.

To clarify; I have to match on "This" and get the third child of row. How would I go about that?

Expected Output: "16600"

Here's what I'm looking at (and I don't know how to select nth children in linq)

```
var query = (from nt in ntd.Descendants("Data").Elements("Out").Skip(1)
             where nt.Element.Attribute("Val").Value == "this"
             select nt.[nth child of row somehow].Attribute("Val").Value)
```

Just to be clear: I'm not allowed to change the XML document structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`.ElementAt(3)`</strike> `.ElementAt(2)` gives you third element from collection - *it's 0-based index ...*

Your sample XML does not totally match the query you've shown, so I decided to follow the schema, not the query:

```
var query = from r in ntd.Root.Elements("Row")
            where (string)r.Attribute("Val") == "THIS"
            select (string)r.Element("Col").Elements("Out").ElementAt(2).Attribute("Val")
```

Comment: I simplified by schema a bit to help with this question. It seems that  that was in error; basically. how does ntd.Root.Elements(); work?

Comment: To answer my own question; Rather than using .Root.Elements I required .Root.Descendants("Row"). Your answer works for the schema I provided thank you! (And after that simple change works for the "real" schema as well")

Comment: @abatishchev How do I save the value of that select statement into an already created object? I know I can new a totally new object and then loop through to move them but but that seems ridiculous .

Comment: LINQ is all about creating objects and querying data. Not about modifying existing data.

Comment: Well, I don't see what you're trying to do. the `query` returns collection of `string`. Do you already have a `List<string>` you wan't to update with that data?

Comment: More like I have multiple linq statements creating an object. It's a pretty hairy situation. I will be posting another question tonight but I'm out of here.